# Backbone.history.navigate(url,{trigger:true, replace: true})

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, browser-history

I used this method to navigate to url, trigger an event and not push url to browser history. But `Backbone.history.navigate(url,{trigger:true, replace: true})` replace previous url from history.
Example: Browser hystory

Before

`localhost:port/url`

`Backbone.history.navigate(url + '/list',{ trigger:true, replace: true })`

Expected: trigger event on route `url + '/list'` and Browser history `localhost:port/url`
Actually: triggering event but Browser history `localhost:port/#url/list`. 
Previous url is replaced

Comment: Is the problem the `#` in the url? The question is not very clear.

Comment: It seems the answer below should be accepted as the correct answer, please note you seemed to have misinterpreted the meaning of replace---it replaces the entry in the _history_ (the address bar always changes on navigation)... but navigation is not the only way to update your app!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what I think you're asking, please correct me if I'm wrong:

"How do I trigger a route in Backbone without updating the URL?"

**Quick Answer**:

You can't. The `replace` option will also not help you there. Here's a snippet from the docs:

> To update the URL without creating an entry in the browser's history, set the replace option to true.

As you can see replace does not affect the update to the URL.

**Subsequent Answer**:

If you don't want the URL to update, this makes me think that showing a list in your application is **not** a major update to your application state. If that's true, then you shouldn't, in my experience, use the `Backbone.history` object to manage it.

If you called this functionality either directly (e.g., through a function) or indirectly (e.g., by dispatching an event) then your app would update and your URL wouldn't.

I like [Derick Baily's Post](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/08/28/dont-execute-a-backbone-js-route-handler-from-your-code/) on how to set up your router structure. It's a bit lengthy but worth a read.

Also, check out [David Sulc's repo](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction) for "A Gentle Introduction to Marionette". I know it's using **Marionette.AppRouter** objects, but the principals are still sound. [Check out this file](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/contacts_app.js) for an example.

As a side note, if the `#` is the problem; [check out this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9542367/disable-backbone-js-hashes-entirely-but-keep-pushstate-in-history). Be wary, however, the `hashChange` option is mostly for x-browser compatibility [according to the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start).